# Moving Swift iOS app to support Apple TV as a new Target

Tags: ios, swift, tvos, apple-tv

Maybe somebody can help, I'm trying to move my app to facilitate a new target for the Apple TV. 
I create the new Storyboard and linked everything the same way as it has been in the iOS application. When I'm trying to start the application I get the following exception, after the `AppDelegate` is executed (before it goes into the `viewDidLoad` of the initial controller.

Any ideas?

```
 2015-09-19 12:24:44.629 App TV[46733:3797033] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalid', reason: 'layer <CATransformLayer: 0x7fc1e0d51fc0> is a part of cycle in its layer tree'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e850105 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f271deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e85003d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   QuartzCore                          0x0000000111d2f74a _ZN2CA5Layer30ensure_transaction_recursivelyEPNS_11TransactionE + 102
    4   QuartzCore                          0x0000000111d2f795 _ZN2CA5Layer30ensure_transaction_recursivelyEPNS_11TransactionE + 177
    5   QuartzCore                          0x0000000111d2f795 _ZN2CA5Layer30ensure_transaction_recursivelyEPNS_11TransactionE + 177
    6   QuartzCore                          0x0000000111d2f795 _ZN2CA5Layer30ensure_transaction_recursivelyEPNS_11TransactionE + 177
    7   QuartzCore                          0x0000000111d37439 _ZN2CA5Layer15insert_sublayerEPNS_11TransactionEP7CALayerm + 389
    8   QuartzCore                          0x0000000111d3782a -[CALayer addSublayer:] + 193
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010d2ce424 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1512
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010d5b1b56 -[UIButton initWithCoder:] + 1424
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010d79dd62 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 705
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010d79da98 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 278
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010d5d1315 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 134
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010d5d1a77 -[UIRuntimeEventConnection initWithCoder:] + 60
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010d79dd62 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 705
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010d79df23 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1154
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010d79da98 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 278
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010d5d0555 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1255
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010d3ad7f2 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 381
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010d3ae11e -[UIViewController loadView] + 178
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010d3ae47d -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 139
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010d3aec7e -[UIViewController view] + 27
    23  UIKit                               0x000000010d289484 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 61
    24  UIKit                               0x000000010d289b81 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 302
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010d29b558 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 43
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010d216063 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4131
    27  UIKit                               0x000000010d21c5a8 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1755
    28  UIKit                               0x000000010d219783 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    29  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011097b7ac -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 192
    30  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011097bb1a -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e77c1b1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e7720dc __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e771593 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e770fa8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    35  UIKit                               0x000000010d2190d5 -[UIApplication _run] + 402
    36  UIKit                               0x000000010d21de09 UIApplicationMain + 171
    37  App TV                  0x000000010d0b8fdd main + 109
    38  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001149699e9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Funny thing happening, apparently the new Apple TV (4th Gen / tvOS v9.0) can't handle 'Word Wrap' on a button, after setting it to 'Truncate Middle' it starts up fine. Maybe an issue in the beta.

Comment: Thanks! I just spent the past day trying to figure this out.  This is still and issue with the GM of 9.0

Comment: "Truncate Tail" also caused the error, with the solution being a switch to "Truncate Middle."

Answer (score 2):

On Xcode 7.2 I had this same error caused by setting the Line Break on a button to 'Character Wrap'. Changing to 'Truncate Middle' stopped the crash.

Answer (score 0):

You can be notified where the exception occurs by activating Exception Breakpoints, then you will be able to see what happens.

You can do so by going on the Breakpoint navigator on Xcode, then on the Plus button at the bottom left.